# Accessing static variable from an object in memory

Tags: java, object, memory, static

Recently, I learned that the static variable could be accessed from an object, in addition to a class name.

I believe that static variables reside in the permanent generation area in the heap, not in the object related area in the heap.

Also, I think that `m1.count` refers the memory position of m1, and add some offset to access the `count` instance variable.

In my logic, `m1.count` should spit error since there is no instance variable called count near `m1` object in memory.

How could it be possible? I want to know how it works in memory.
Here is the code:

```
class Member{
    public static int count;
}

public static void main(){    
    Member m1 = new Member();
    System.out.println(m1.count); // ???
}
```

Comment: you are not the only one. many people believe this "feature" is a mistake in the language design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that static variables reside in the permanent generation area in the heap,

such static fields can be anywhere on the heap.

> I think that m1.count refers the memory position of m1,

`static` fields ignore the reference.  The reference can be `null` and the code will run fine.

> I want to know how it works in memory

There is a special object for the `static` fields of the class.  You can get this  the with a heap dump.  The reference is incidental.

This

```
Member m1 = new Member();
System.out.println(m1.count);
```

is the same as

```
Member m1 = null;
System.out.println(m1.count);
```

which is the same as

```
System.out.println(Member.count);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that static variables reside in the permanent generation area in the heap, not in the object related area in the heap.

Well to put it more simply they reside in the class, not in the object.

> Also, I think that m1.count refers the memory position of m1, and add some offset to access the count instance variable.

No. It essentially does `m1.class.count,` but the `m1.class` part happens at compile time.

> In my logic, m1.count should spit error since there is no instance variable called count near m1 object in memory.

*Ergo* your logic is wrong.

Comment: Lawrey suggested that m1 could be null. Then, what is the output of null.class?

Comment: @PeterHwang `null.class` is not the correct construct. `Member.class` will still be the `Class<Member>`, while `d.class` will NPE.